# Influxdb subqueries to return two variables

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to extract an average of "stockA" and "stockB" timeseries using subqueries:

```
SELECT (("stockA"+"stockB")/2 )

AS "average"

FROM
(SELECT (("askPrice1" + "bidPrice1")/2) AS "stockA", (("askPrice1" + "bidPrice1")/2) AS "stockB" 

FROM "data"."orderbook_stockA", "data"."orderbook_stockB" 

WHERE( "instrument" = 'a' OR "instrument" = 'b') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY "instrument"  fill(previous))
```

However, it returns two seperate result of "stockA" and "stockB" instead of the average that I wanted to achieve. Can anyone please help me? Much appreciated as I am still new to this.

Comment: Now I noticed the problem is that I need to select "stockA" and "stockB" with seperate FROM. i.e. SELECT (("askPrice1" + "bidPrice1")/2) AS "stockA" FROM "data"."orderbook_stockA" AND SELECT (("askPrice1" + "bidPrice1")/2) AS "stockB" FROM "data"."orderbook_stockB". However it still doesn't work, can anyone please help?